# Triggering scroll event for Lazy Load jQuery plugin

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-lazyload

I am working with [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) to load images only when they are visible and the images that are first visible from a popout menu are not loading. All of the images are located within `<li>` elements on an unordered list. When I start to scroll down the list, the images start loading as they should. But how do I get the few first images to show when the menu is first opened?

I have tried to trigger the `scroll` event, along with other events, but none of them have seemed to work. The `<ul>` is located within a menu that pops out from an "infobar" (just a bar with links at the top of the page). I was thinking maybe this had something to do with the fact that they (the images) aren't readily visible on page load?

Here is my lazyload initialization:

```
$("img.lazy", this.list).show().lazyload({
  effect: "fadeIn",
  container: this.list,
  threshold: 50
});

$(this.list).trigger("scroll"); // tried this
$(document).trigger("scroll"); // and that

// this.list is the unordered list
```

I have also tried to initialize the plugin with `mouseenter` and `scrollstop` as the `event` properties, then triggering those events, no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second `this.list` is where you are going wrong. Lazy Load works on `<img>` elements and not on `<ul>`

```
$("img.lazy", this.list).trigger("scroll"); // should work
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any difference. Maybe because the actual `ul` isn't visible yet when I trigger the scroll event? When the menu is opened, it has several things to load before it is actually displayed. Going to try it out in a few different places in time

Comment: Yep, it was a combination of what you suggested and what I suspected. If I call `trigger` after the list is actually visible, it loads the images as expected. Thanks!